# Ionic 2 : Get the header of a response in http request

Tags: javascript, http, angular, header, ionic2

I want to have some information about the response when I request an API with http in Ionic 2 / Angular 2.
Informations like : response time, response size ... ect.

I use this code :

```
let url : "[myUrl]";
this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

I want to get the response header.

Someone know how to do that ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.http.get(url).map(res => {
    console.log(res.headers); // Print http header
    return res.json();
}).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Angular `Http` request returns an `Observable` which contains all the information the server has passed. So you can access `headers` from the response as `res.headers`. To obtain the size of the response body you can use,

`res.headers.get('Content-Length')`

assuming this is present in the headers. So it depends on the information the response carries rather not what angular provides.

Response time information depends on what exactly you are looking for. For server response time in `node.js` you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/response-time) package. Then in response , `response time` can be obtained with

`res.headers.get('X-Response-Time')`

If you want the total response time (including the network delay ) you will have use `JavaScript` timer and find the time difference between request and response.

So the information you are looking for mainly relies on the server response rather than angular. And beware of `CORS` in browser ( `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in response header ) . You can understand more about headers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers). Hope it helps.

Comment: Hum thanks but in the two case the log return me "null" ?

Comment: console.log(res.headers.get('Content-Length'));

Comment: ``CORS`` can hide headers on client side. You will have add ``Access-Control-Expose-Headers`` in response header to allow access to headers in response. Hope it helped.

Comment: And how can I do that please ? :)

Comment: I try this : 
`headers.append('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', "true");

this.http.get(url, {headers : headers}).map(res => {

    console.log(res);

    return res.json();

}).subscribe(res => {

    console.log(res);

});`

Comment: You have to do it server side. Check out your back-end docs for exposing headers.

Comment: Oh ok ! But I can have this information with google chrome console. So I need a special autorisation to use it in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can. In the map function you can get the all the information regarding HTTP call. You can do whatever you want with the result (I've added only a console.log)

```
this.http.get(url).map(res => {
    console.log(res); // Print http details
    return res.json();
}).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Oh thanks ! :D But I don't have the response size or the response time ?

Comment: That's what Response object contains :) I hope so that Angular team will add more things.