# Obtain response Headers HttpClient

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am trying to get the response Headers of a HttpClient response

Like this:

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

obtainData(url) {
  return this.http.get(url,{withCredentials: true, headers: headers})
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.headers)
  }).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Whith HttpClient the response is only the json body, due to this `response.headers` throws and exception.

I have already tried this on request options `{observe: 'response'}` but it not works.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: instead of using toPromise, try map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41394756/ionic-2-get-the-header-of-a-response-in-http-request and subscribe https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: `{observe: 'response'}` should be correct. when you add this, what get printed in your console log?

Comment: `{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null}`

Comment: @Hanzo Try doing the `{observe: 'response'}` & in your then, print out `response.headers.get('header-name')` where `header-name` is whatever response header you are looking for

Comment: @LLai you're right it works. But, It work with post request? With post request it throw a exception

Comment: @Hanzo What is the exception?

Comment: Never mind, it works

Comment: Do you Know wich is the new version of URLSearchParams on HttpClient. I need to do a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request